# Redirect to Parent Detail Page After Updating Both Parent and Child Objects

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I redirect my page to parent detail page upon updating both parent and child objects? Both records are saving successfully, but everytime I click the save button, it doesn't go back to the master detail record page.

Here's my controller:

**EditBothAC**

```
public class EditBothAC{

    private ApexPages.StandardController con;
    public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}

    public EditBothAC(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        con = controller;

        contacts = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE accountid=:con.getId() ORDER BY FirstName ASC LIMIT 5];

    }

    public PageReference save(){


        con.save();

        update contacts;


        PageReference result = ApexPages.currentPage();
        result.setRedirect(true);
        return result;
    }

}
```

And here's my vf page:

**EditBothACPage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="EditBothAC">

    <apex:form >

            <apex:pageBlock title="Account Detail">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Description}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contacts">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="c">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!c.FirstName}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!c.LastName}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Email}"/>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ApexPages.currentPage()
```

returns current page url.

This would get back you to account detail page:

```
PageReference result = new PageReference('/'+con.getId());
```